# Xcode How read numbers on a Text View (or label?)

Tags: ios, swift

this is my first post.
I'm new in the Xcode Word.
At the moment I'm working to a simple application and I need to read a number from a box and after a lot of calculations write the result in an other text view or label.
I need how to read a numbers or a string from a box after writing (text view, label or other).
Thank you very much for your answers

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question could use some more detail — are you asking how to access the text inside a text field? Have you visited the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfield ?

Comment: Hi, I thy to make an example: I need to have a box where put a number for example 50 and read this number; after use it in a function for example a Square or equation and give a result. For you what are the best way in Xcode to make this? Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 1):

if you are sure that your textfield will accept only numbers, one of the possible ways could be:

```
yourTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.decimalPad
```

in this way, when the user will tap on the textField, you may use the numeric keypad.
At this point your viewController must implement `UItextFieldDelegate`

```
yourTextField.delegate = self
```

and then use the method, called when textfield loses focus:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
var valueInserted : Float = NSString(string: textField.text!).floatValue
```

}

Comment: Sorry the first part work but I don't understand where and how implement the function. Thank you very much. Do you speak Italian?

Comment: yes. nel tuo controller(che dovrà essere conforme al protocollo UItextFieldDelegate) devi implementare la funzione textFieldDidEndEditing...
in questo modo vedrai che quando il tuo text field perderà il focus, allora potrai prendere il testo ed effettuare il controllo di quest'ultimo.

Comment: Purtroppo non riesco a capire come implementare la funzione, ho provato a copiarla nel View controller a poi a inserire la stringa Mytextfield.delegate = self ma mi dice che non è possibile: "Cannot assign value Type 'ViewController' to UItextField"

Answer (score 0):

Drag a UITextView inside the scene (in the storyboard)
Create an outlet between the UITextView and ViewController.swift 
in ViewController.swift you will have something like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTextView:UITextView!
```

You must also get a reference for your label

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel:UILabel!
```

you can now access to the content(input) of your textView by checking the text property:

```
var input = myTextView.text
```

This will be a string, that you can try to convert to an Int. Once you have a result to display, set the label text:

```
myLabel.text = result
```

Comment: @AttilioPiccolo you can get the first one for free if you sign up to the newsletter. It's very well explained :)